# Generating a Cyclic Spectrum

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics, cycle

I'm trying to generate a spectrum of all the cyclic combinations from my peptide.

Here's my the code for the linear spectrum:

```
#For example: LEQN
#L:113 E:129 Q:128 N:114
    peptide = [113,129,128,114]
        for a in peptide:
            for i in peptide[b:]:
                s+= i
                spectrum.append(s)
            s=0
            b += 1

spectrum.sort()
print spectrum
```

**Outputs:** [113, 114, 128, 129, 242, 242, 257, 370, 371, 484]

My code successful adds these sums L(113), E(129), Q(128), N(114), LE(113+129), LEQ(113+129+128), LEQN(113+129+128+114), EQ(129+128), EQN(129+128+114), QN(128+114)

**BUT** is missing QNL(128+113+114), NL(114+113), NLE(114+113+129)

Ex. QNL should be 128+114+113 which is the summation of elements 2, 3, and 1.
NL is 114+133 which is the summation of elements 3 and 0. And NLE is 113+114+129 which is the summation of elements 3, 0, 1.

*I wouldn't need to add EQNL or QNLE because they are exact same thing as LEQN.

*However LE=242 and QN=242 have the same mass but are NOT the same thing.

**Expected Output:** 113, 114, 128, 129, 227(N+L), 242, 242, 257, 355(Q+N+L), 356(N+L+E), 370, 371, 484

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, could you specify the expected output and what a cyclic combination is?

Comment: Can't you just duplicate the peptide in tandem and loop through peptide[0:4], peptide[2:6], peptide[3:6], peptide[3:7], etc?

Comment: What do you mean @heathobrien? Ok I added more details along with my expected output.

Comment: See my answer for what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all the possible sublists, for each length up to the length of the `peptide` list and for each starting position in that list, wrapping around at the end of the list. One way to do this would be using [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

peptide = [113, 129, 128, 114]
spectrum = []
for num in range(1, len(peptide)):
    for start in range(len(peptide)):
        group = islice(cycle(peptide), start, start + num)
        spectrum.append(sum(group))
spectrum.append(sum(peptide)) # add the entire list only once
```

This way, `sorted(spectrum)` ends up as `[113, 114, 128, 129, 227, 242, 242, 257, 355, 356, 370, 371, 484]`, which seems to be what you wanted.

Not sure, though, how this scales to much longer lists of peptides (I'd assume in practice those lists have more than four elements).

Answer (score 1):

```
peptide = [113,129,128,114]
peptide *= 2
spectrum = []
for i in range(len(peptide)/2):
    for j in range(i+1,i+4):
       s = 0
       for a in peptide[i:j]:
           s+= a
       spectrum.append(s)
spectrum.sort()
print spectrum
```

Comment: Admitedly, that doesn't include the sum for the entire peptide

Comment: This code would be more useful it there was additional comments and explanation.